# ng : Can't have multiple template bindings on one element . Use only one attribute named template or prefixed with *

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using angular5 , i'm not able to use *dropdownMenu with *ngFor , i get this error :

```
ng : Can't have multiple template bindings on one element . Use only one attribute named template or prefixed with *
```

This is the code :

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" (click)="ListUsers()">
          List of users <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" *ngFor="let c of listUsers">
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item">{{c.Firstname}} {{c.lastName}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Can't have multiple template bindings on one element` means `*dropdownMenu` and `*ngIf` directive can't be together in one element as both are structural directive.

(The `*` marks indicates that they are structural directive)

**EDIT (Solution):**

apply `*ngFor` on `li`, not on `ul`.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" (click)="ListUsers()">
          List of users <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
            <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let c of listUsers">
                <a class="dropdown-item">
                 {{c.Firstname}} {{c.lastName}}
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi , yes i'm sur it's *dropdownMenu , the button won't work without the * , any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Please, tell me the name of the 3rd party component

Comment: i'm sorry , what do you mean by the 3rd party component?

Comment: From where you're getting this `*dropdownMenu` ?

Comment: In fact this is a template that i've found in github , so there is a lot of files i don't really know from where it come from , i thought it comes with ngx-bootstrap that this template uses .

Comment: I updated the answer with the solution. Please give a try

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer & give upvote. :)